# Using iOS Gamekit without showing the pickers

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, wifi, gamekit

I'm very new to Gamekit.  Can you implement Gamekit in your iOS app without showing the UI.  Basically automate the selection of wifi vs bluetooth and then the connecting to peers?